# php comparison operator in assignment

Tags: php

I saw a small php quiz online that contained the following code:

```
$somevalue[[ 2 <=['-']=> 2][1]] = $somestring;
```

My question is, what does the part before the assignment do?

```
$somevalue[[ 2 <=['-']=> 2][1]]
```

`<=` looks like the comparison operator but in that case it is comparing `2` to `'-'`?

Comment: That middle value is an array whose only value is a string (specifically a dash), not just a string with a dash in it.

Comment: Does it mean that we can replace `2 <=['-']=> 2` by `2 <= array('-') => 2` ? That's a lot better, indeed ! :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP's array initialization syntax looks like this:

```
$arr = [ key => value ];
```

So in this part:

```
2 <=['-']=> 2
```

The 'key' is the result of the expression `2 <= ['-']`, which according [to this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) evaluates to `true` (an array is always greater than what you are comparing it to, unless it's another array). Because PHP arrays keys are either integers or strings, the boolean result is implicitly cast to the integer `1`, so you end up with:

```
1 => 2
```

So the simplified expression:

```
[ 1 => 2 ][1]
```

Will evaluate to the second element of the array we've just created (PHP array's are 0-based), so this will simplify to:

```
2
```

So at the end we end up with:

```
$somevalue[2] = $somestring;
```

Comment: Nice explanation. I got stuck on `2 <= ['-']` and didn't get why it resulted in "true", but now I do! :-)

Comment: The hell of type castings.

Answer (score 4):

To understand this you need to break the statement in parts,

```
echo 2 <=['-'];//return true
```

[PHP Comparison operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

After this the statement will be

```
$somevalue[[1 => 2][1]] = $somestring;
```

Here you see the `array` index `1` has values `2`. After this the last index which is `1`, from the array `[1 => 2]` it will return `2`, so finally you will have

```
$somevalue[2] = $somestring;
```